# Find $f(x,y)$ whose level curves have weird looks

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $f(x,y)$ that have level curves $y = \frac{x^{2}}{k}-k$ for every positive height $k$.

I've tried many examples but couldn't find one that fits. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: My strategy was to separate $k$ from $x$ and $y$. But that gave me $x^2 - ky = k^{2}$. So I thought the function should probably have a square root due to the $k^{2}$ and then maybe a fraction inside the square root because of the $ky$. Then I had $f(x,y) = \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{k}-y}$, which I know can't be right because of the $k$ inside $f(x,y)$. I didn't know how to get rid of the $k$ and there's where I was stuck.

Comment: Show please, what exactly you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is make $k$ the subject. That is literally it.

$$y=\frac{x^2}{k}-k \iff k^2+yk-x^2=0 \iff \frac{-y\pm\sqrt{y^2+4x^2}}{2}=k $$

Since your $k$ is positive, we take

$$f(x,y)=\frac{-y+\sqrt{y^2+4x^2}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I had to separate $k$ from $x$ and $y$ somehow. But it didn't occur to me that I just need to solve for $k$.